# my rails dropdown form generates nil no matter what is selected how do i fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I am new at RoR, I have been searching and searching but can't seem to find a solution. I have a simple form:

```
<%= form_for @case do |f| %>
<%= f.select( :case, options_for_select([['CASE1','CASE1'],['CASE2','CASE2'],['CASE3','CASE3'],['CASE4','CASE4']])) %>
<% end %>
```

That is in my nav bar. It is not based on any table in the DB.

Controller:

```
class MyAppController < ApplicationController
before_filter :initialize_remote_user

   def self.search(name)
     @results = MyApp.search(params[:name])
     @case = params[:case]
    end

   def result
     @results =  MyApp.where("name = ?",params[:name]).order("item_scan_date ASC")
     puts @results.inspect
   end

   def update
    end

   def change
     end

   def show
    @case = params[:case].inspect
   end

   def create
   end

   def new
   end

   def index
   end

  private

  def name_params
     params.require(:name).permit(:name)
  end

  def case_params
     params.require(:case).permit(:case, :id)
  end
```

When I have `@case = params[:case].inspect` it doesn't have any errors, but it doesn't pull the data from the `<%= form_for @case do |f| %>`

I have tried

```
def show
@case = Case.find(params[:case])
end
```

but end up with `NameError uninitialized constant MyAppController::Case` error at `@case = Case.find(params[:case])`

I can't seem to get `@case` to pull up anything but `nil`

If I have `@case = params[:case]` in `def show` I get 'ArgumentError First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error at `<%= form_for @case do |f| %>`

Comment: As a style note, `where(name: params[:name])` is preferable to writing out the SQL itself.

Comment: What is `case`? If you're using `form_for` it should be some kind of model you're working with. Otherwise you need to do it with the low-level `form_tag` method.

Comment: @ todman `case` is just a variable name. I changed `form_for` to `form_tag` and I get NoMethodError undefined method `select` for nil:NilClass. If I change `select` to `select_tag` same error message. I have followed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html before I got the `form_for` to actually work without errors.

Comment: @tadman that `where` query is based on an input form. It took me awhile to get it to actually work.

Comment: It's `select_tag` for those not intrinsically bound to a form. That method should be defined in your view. The reason `form_for` was "working" was because you had the form right, but it's testing against the wrong data.

Comment: @tadman how would I define the method in my view to pull whatever is selected from the form?

Comment: You don't define the method, you just use it. The `_tag` methods work independent of the "form helper" system and work on arbitrary data.

Comment: `case` is a `variable` or `attribute of Case` model?

Comment: I still not sure, for some reason I think it has to do with the form location maybe, since the form is not called in view/controller I am trying to pull it into.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple_form for your forms see: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form and read the documentation under Collections to handle input for `:case`

Also make sure your create and new  methods aren't empty, or else your form won't save.

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately due to weird work setup, I cannot install new gems